# Fixing the underside of the roof

Tags: roof, roofing

We had a hurricane roll through and it's almost impossible to get someone to come look at our issue.

The wind bent this part several different ways and it wont go back with out large holes / gaps in it.

Note: I'm referring to the part that is connected to the under side of the roof.  The part laying on the roof is just trash.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

**Questions**:

1. What is it called?
2. Where can I purchase a section to replace it?
3. How can I fix it myself and do I need any special tools?

Comment: Can you provide more pictures, please? If possible, from the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is it called?

Soffit vent.

---

> Where can I purchase a section to replace it?

Feel free to Google "soffit vent" or "soffit vent strip" depending on your locale. They're usually sold in 8' lengths.

---

> How can I fix it myself and do I need any special tools?

A pair of tin snips work fine.

---

> The wind bent this part several different ways and it wont go back with out large holes / gaps in it.

It should go back in just the way it was no problem unless:

1. Your roof has been bent
2. There's additional damage which is not revealed in your photos
3. The original installer hack-jobbed it just enough to get the job done so now it's your problem to cut it nicely to fit properly

Comment: Hurricane winds did a job on a lot of things. I don't see where there is any indication that a "hack job" was done.  A hurricane leaves people shell shocked. If you are not someone that does home repairs things can appear to be overwhelming.

Comment: @RMDman I don't see broken soffit strip pieces so what is your assessment for it not fitting back in easily?

Comment: once it is bent, it is a pain to get back together, and often looks poor or like that "hack job".  The "j" chanel is bent up also and may have to be reattached to the wall. If the OP doesn't even know what the parts are they are not likely to have the skill to put the pieces back together.

Comment: On the other hand, doing the job in the ordinary way will create a vulnerable repair that will fail again next hurricane.  Because standard building methods aren't made to hold up to hurricanes.

Comment: A) I would call it "ventilated soffit", B) it looks like the fascia trim (on the right of the picture) wasn't installed properly or was pulled down by the wind. It shouldn't sit so low as to allow the soffit to sag down like that. Since I see no (obvious) signs of damage to it, it does appear to be a bit of a "hack job" by the installer, though I could easily be proven wrong by better pics of the situation.

Comment: I would be hesitant to criticize any issue with a home after a hurricane. Like the OP I went through Ian. The wind alone tore out structures and trees without anything hitting them. A friend had a bedroom window blow out when a door was opened. Was it a hack job. NO, just a window that could not resist the forces it was subject to.  This storm was the worst in 100 years in Fla.  I've been through 8 in 33 yrs here. This one was bad...and leaves a scar...and yes I'm a little sensitive to any criticism of tradesmen when I new their quality of work, but saw it torn  like it was made of paper.

Comment: @RMDman If you look at [picture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1IkV.jpg) then you will notice that the fascia runs into the perpendicular roof at an angle not consistent with the soffit track which runs along the wall. The fact that the joint seems to be sealed still tells me that the hurricane did not break the roof. That roof framing seems subpar so the soffit installer had a subpar starting point. OP should provide another angle of the damage because that drip-edge looks concerning as well.

Comment: That facia trim appears to me to have been pulled down. Something that is not uncommon here in Fla. where there were high wind situations. The aluminum contractors have to walk a tight line between anchoring the facia trim and not placing too many nails for water to seep to the underlying board and rot it. The framers will not use PT for the facia board because it warps too much.  However the soffit and facia trim   can be fine for years or even a decade...then a hurricane hits.

Comment: @RMDman More pictures are needed to verify your assessment.

Answer (score 0):

That is soffiting. It is not structural and is there to close the overhang of the roof and yet allow air flow to vent the attic. It comes in 12ft pieces and has to be cut to the length you need for each section. It is held in place by a "j" channel that is attached to the sidewall and the facia trim at the outer edge of the roof. The big box stores have it and the facia. However usually only in white and brown. You may also try aluminum product and roofing contractors. Yes they are all busy now. What you have is very minor compared to the folks that don't have a roof or even a home anymore. You may have to order it and be patient.  It takes some skill to fit the pieces that are cut together, and sometimes they need to be stapled to the facia board before replacing the facia trim. Trying calling a handyman. Most should have the knowhow to do that repair.